# Where are pip package available to download source of sudo apt-get install python3-pip?

Tags: pip, sudo, apt

I want to make a binary of `pip` for all the systems but I am not able to locate the source files for pip.

Is there any url from which I can get the source files for pip.

PS: I don't want the pip package source files that are available on git. They can only create a wheel package. I want to create a binary e.g. It is available in linux at `/usr/bin/pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, might be easier to just grab them from anaconda. Anaconda has all the binaries for pip:
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pip/files

This is what is downloaded when you do:
conda install pip